# Changing some default template parameters

Tags: c++

Consider a template class like this:

```
template <int opt1 = 1,
          bool opt2 = false,
          bool opt3 = true,
          int opt4 = 50>
class X  { };
```

I try to change just one parameter, but it seems that C++ can't do that. Or am I wrong? How to achieve something like this:

```
X<opt2 = true> x;
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, all parameters, even default ones, need to be provided from left to right up until the last default parameter you want to set

Comment: @emartel I hoped that this was not the answer :-)

Comment: AFAIK, positional arguments are not supported in the language - am afraid you are going to have to specify all pre-ceeding parameters too.

Comment: @Martin I didn't give too much time to C++11 so maybe there's something else you can do

Comment: @emartel there isn't much that C++11 adds that helps. You can fake this by making it look like `X<opt2<true>>` (boost uses this technique in places) instead, and variadic templates simplify that implementation, but that's it. If no one writes an answer with this before I get home, I will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Boost version mentioned by *R. Martinho Fernandes* works something like this:

1. define a number of option types (they can be empty tag structures, or templated on `bool` to enable/disable, or whatever)

   ```
   template <int I>  struct option_1: public std::integral_constant<int, I>  {};
   template <bool B> struct option_2: public std::integral_constant<bool, B> {};
   template <bool B> struct option_3: public std::integral_constant<bool, B> {};
   template <int I>  struct option_4: public std::integral_constant<int, I>  {};
   ```
2. define some kind of typelist of your default values (I'll hide it in a namespace along with the existing template class)

   ```
   namespace impl {
     typedef typelist<option_1<1>, option_2<false>,
                      option_3<true>, option_4<50>> X_defaults;

     template <int opt1, bool opt2, bool opt3, int opt4>
     class X { /* ... */ };
   }
   ```
3. write a `get` mechanism to extract an option from a suitable typelist (including a version which falls back on the provided default)

   Once you have all that, you can write a wrapper class that handles all the options and delegates to your existing class, eg.

   ```
   template <typename... Options>
   class X: public impl::X<
       get<option_1, typelist<Options...>, impl::X_defaults>::value,
       get<option_2, typelist<Options...>, impl::X_defaults>::value,
       get<option_3, typelist<Options...>, impl::X_defaults>::value,
       get<option_4, typelist<Options...>, impl::X_defaults>::value>
   {
   };
   ```

Your final invocation now looks like:

```
X<option_2<true>> x;
```

---

The `typelist` and `get` parts are left as an exercise (along with lots of errors, most likely) for the OP, a kindly passing editor, or me when I have more time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// opt1 = 1 (provided), opt2 = true (provided), opt3 = true (default), opt4 = 50 (default)
X<1, true> x;
```

If you want to change the default vale of the **second** parameter, you must specify the value of the previous one too. You cannot reffer parameters by their name, the parameters have a name and a position, the fact is that you don't need to name them at all into the declaration:

```
template <int = 1,
      bool = false,
      bool = true,
      int = 50>
class X  { };
```

For this reason, you cannot define default values for parameters *in the middle* of a parameter list:

```
void f(int a, int b = 0, int c); // Error!
```

If the previous function declaration was legal, what this call will do?:

```
f(1, 2);
```

It will call `f` with `a = 1, b= 0, c = 2` or `a = 1, b = 2, c = unknown`?

Comment: That's clear, but the question was if enumerating all the preceding arguments is really necessary. It seems so even in C++11.